# Possibly mistaken empty statement warning

Tags: c#

I'm getting a “Possibly mistaken empty statement” warning when I compile this code:

```
class Lab6
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program fileOperation = new Program();

        Console.WriteLine("Enter a name for the file:");
        string fileName = Console.ReadLine();

        if (File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The file name exists. Do you want to continue appendng ? (Y/N)");
            string persmission = Console.ReadLine();

            if (persmission.Equals("Y") || persmission.Equals("y"))
            {
                fileOperation.appendFile(fileName);
            }
        }
        else
        {

            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileName)) ;
            fileOperation.appendFile(fileName);
        }
    }

    public void appendFile(String fileName)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter new content for the file - type Done and press enter to finish editing:");
        string newContent = Console.ReadLine();
        while (newContent != "Done")
        {
            File.AppendAllText(fileName, (newContent + Environment.NewLine));
            newContent = Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to fix it, but I couldn't. What does this warning mean and where's the problem?

Comment: Please try harder next time when asking a question. See my edit, I tried to make it at least a bit more readable and understandable. Also, a title “Hi, I'm new…” is **really** inapproriate. The title **must** be a short summary of your problem.

Comment: "where's the problem?" -- The error message, which you neglected to provide in full, contains the line number of the error. You have a `using` statement that sets `sw` but you never use `sw`.

Answer (score 9):

A “Possibly mistaken empty statement” warning means there's a statement in your code, would should be compound (i.e. contain a “body” like this: `statement { ... more statement ... }`), but instead of the body there a semicolon `;` which terminates the statement. You should immediately know what and where's wrong, just by double-clicking on the warning a navigating to the respective line of code.

Common mistakes like this look like:

```
if (some condition) ; // mistakenly terminated
   do_something();    // this is always executed

if (some condition);  // mistakenly terminated
{
    // this is always executed
    ... statement supposed to be the 'then' part, but in fact not ...
}

using (mySuperLock.AcquiredWriterLock());  // mistakenly terminated
{
    ... no, no, no, this not going to be executed under a lock ...
}
```

Specifically, in your code in this statement:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileName)) ;
```

there's a `;` at the end, making the `using` empty (=useless). The immediately following line of code:

```
fileOperation.appendFile(fileName);
```

has nothing to do with any `StreamWriter` whatsoever, so there's apparently *something* missing in your code (or something *left over* — the `using`, probably?).

Comment: +1. MSDN information about [CS0642](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9x19t380%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) can be easily obtained by clicking "F1" when error selected in VS.